# remind about shared folder in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-2007, power-automate

I need to understand whether it is possible to create flow or smth like this to remind people about shared folder with them for example every Monday and send email as this one everytime?[image]

Because now I shared folder with people, they got such message as in picture with link of that folder and when they want to open it Microsoft sends verification code, also  they receive message every Monday about new file added but some of people didn't open that first letter in their mail about shared folder and after sending email about shared file they can't open it so I just want that they would get each time notification that folder is shared with them.

Also tried to do flow with added file link and folder link but still if person didn't opened first letter about shared folder that link of folder doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the challenge is that this is just a standard notification which somebody receives in their own mailbox. You might be able to monitor such a mailbox for unread messages where the subject contains (shared a folder with you). But that is just one mailbox and I am also assuming that the person receiving the email is an employee who has a mailbox within the organisation. In other words, I would suggest to just probably guide/train/educate them about not ignoring these e-mails instead of automating these type of complex reminders ;) Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Thanks :) But is it possible that they need to open that message about shared folder each time they want to open that link with shared files in that folder? Because I have tested it with my personal mail and for example If I got message about share folder yesterday I should open that link and then  I can open shared file link as well, but today I couldn't open that shared file link again

Comment: Depends a bit on your orgs Sharing settings setup. There are several settings which can influence this behaviour. Anyone links can expire after a certain amount of days: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/turn-external-sharing-on-or-off#advanced-settings-for-anyone-links. Verification codes might require reauth after a certain amount of days: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/turn-external-sharing-on-or-off#more-external-sharing-settings